# How to select only arguments containing numbers in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to count arguments containing numbers in an array.

```
array = ['Cat', '3Dog', 'Fish', 'Horse5']
=> "There is two arguments containing numbers"
```

Comment: edit you question , as code is not visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an argument to count in the way for it to match the words against any pattern.

```
array = ["Cat", "3Dog", "Fish", "Horse5"]
puts array.count {|x| x.match /[0-9]/ } # this will output 2.
```

Comment: ...or `x.match? /\d/`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get by following,

```
array = ["Cat", "3Dog", "Fish", "Horse5"]
array.count { |x| x =~ /\d/ }
# => 2

# even another form can be used also
array.count(&/\d/.method(:=~))
# => 2
```

Answer (score 2):

By using grep command

```
array = ["Cat", "3Dog", "Fish", "Horse5"]
2.2.9 :021 > array.grep(/\d/)
 => ["3Dog", "Horse5"] 
2.2.9 :022 > array.grep(/\d/).count
 => 2
```

Comment: When compared to using `Array#count` this has the disadvantage that it produces a temporary array.